# How to copy a JSON object in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json object that hold some data, and I'm doing a search on that object and when the result match I want to save it to another object. What is the best way to do it.

I need some help copying the data I want to the new variable.

Here is what I have.

```
myjson = JSON.parse(jsonData);
for(var x=0; x<myjson.ROWCOUNT;x++){
    if(myjson.DATA.PARTNUMBER[x].search(regex) != -1){
        console.log(myjson.DATA.PARTNUMBER[x]);
    }
}
```

Where I have the console.log that display the partnumber, how can I make it so it copies all the content from the X row?

myjson has 4 columns (ID,PARTNUMBER,DESCRIPTION,PRICE) but I'm only searching on the partnumber. I need to copy all to the new json object.

thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to filter, not to copy?

Comment: You could insert it into an attribute in the DOM (such as an #ID) and retrieve it as needed.

Comment: I think my answer matches what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your object using clone function from that post
[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

It copies your object not depending on its structure.

Answer (score 0):

myjson.DATA[x] is a reference to the object that contains the matched PARTNUMBER. Depending on what you want to do with it, you could it to an array for future accessing.  E.g.:

```
myCopies = [];
myjson = JSON.parse(jsonData);
for(var x=0; x<myjson.ROWCOUNT;x++){
    if(myjson.DATA.PARTNUMBER[x].search(regex) != -1){
        console.log(myjson.DATA.PARTNUMBER[x]);
        myCopies.push(myjson.DATA[x]);
    }
}

// myCopies now contains references to all objects matched by partnumber
```

Comment: I have a resultOBJ variable that is blank, so when it matches I want to add the data to the resultOBJ variable.

Comment: Will there only be one match or multiple matches?

Comment: Ben, it could have multiple matches.

Answer (score -1):

Simple way is to hard copy all your properties if there is a matched object

```
var myjson = JSON.parse(jsonData),
    output = [],
    matchedObj
;

for(var x=0; x<myjson.ROWCOUNT;x++){
    if(myjson.DATA.PARTNUMBER[x].search(regex) != -1){
        output.push({
            ID: myjson.DATA.ID[x],
            PARTNUMBER: myjson.DATA.PARTNUMBER[x],
            DESCRIPTION: myjson.DATA.DESCRIPTION[x],
            PRICE: myjson.DATA.PRICE[x]
        });
    }
}

console.log(output);
```

Another way, is to define a simple function to clone all properties of the matched object

```
var myjson = JSON.parse(jsonData),
    output = [],
    matchedObj,
    clone = function(data, i) {
        var copy = {};

        for(var attribute in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(attribute )) {
                copy[attribute] = data[attribute][i];
            }
        }

        return copy;
    }
;


for(var x=0; x<myjson.ROWCOUNT;x++){
    if(myjson.DATA.PARTNUMBER[x].search(regex) != -1){
        output.push(clone(myjson.DATA, x));
    }
}

console.log(output);
```